# Send disabled Listbox data to server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm working on a website where there are several cases where some input data should be visible but disabled for user input. Since the data of disabled inputs aren't sent back to server I always added an hidden input to send back to the server. That way the data wasn't overwritten by null values.

Now I have a problem when rendering a disabled ListBox. For the moment I render a copy of that ListBox, hidden for the user. Is there a better approach to get the same results?

Code to illustrate:

```
@*Works fine*@
@if (Model.OnEdit)
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Contract)
  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Contract, 
                        Model.ContractList, 
                        new { disabled = "disabled" })
}

@if (Model.OnEdit)
{
  @*Otherwise the items will be updated to null*@
  @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Items, 
                   Model.ItemList, 
                   new { @class = "hidden" })
  @Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.Items, 
                   Model.ItemList, 
                   new { disabled = "disabled" })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little step aside:

It's not a common use case of inputs, becouse disabled inputs are treated like they was not changed by user, so the one commonly dont want to send their data to server.

So first of all you should think carefully about "why does your is different?" and "should it be different at all?".
If the data is the same as it was then why do we need it back?

Answer:

There is no better way to send this data without using javascript.

If you have dynamic form with complex client side behavior then I would use javascript and collect data from disabled inputs with:

```
var listData = $('#ContractList').find(":selected").val();
var data = $('#form').serialize();
data.ContractList = listData;
$.post('ajax/test.html', data, function(result) {
    $('.result').html(result);
});
```